# How to reset 'Advance' tab on table property?

Tags: tinymce

I want to use bootstrap table in my site without any mess up class, style. I just want to add bootstrap class. I can add these class in table properties general settings as follows:

```
function bootstrap_classes_tinymce($settings)
{
    $styles = array(
        array(
            'title' => 'None',
            'value' => ''
        ),
        array(
            'title' => 'Table',
            'value' => 'table',
        ),
        array(
            'title' => 'Striped',
            'value' => 'table table-striped table-hover',
        ),
        array(
            'title' => 'Bordered',
            'value' => 'table table-bordered table-hover',
        ),
    );

    $settings['table_class_list'] = json_encode($styles);

    return $settings;
}

add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', 'bootstrap_classes_tinymce');
```

Now I want to remove additional style like this default value:
[image]

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

To customize default styles:

```
$styles = array('width'=>'100%');
$settings['table_default_styles'] = json_encode($styles);
```

To disable advance tab:

```
$settings['table_advtab'] = false;
```

Complete code at functions.php:

```
function bootstrap_classes_tinymce($settings)
{
     // to customize more please visit: https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/table/#table_default_styles
     // Add bootstrap class inside <table> tag
    $classes = array(
        array(
            'title' => 'None',
            'value' => ''
        ),
        array(
            'title' => 'Table',
            'value' => 'table',
        ),
        array(
            'title' => 'Striped',
            'value' => 'table table-striped table-hover',
        ),
        array(
            'title' => 'Bordered',
            'value' => 'table table-bordered table-hover',
        ),
    );

    $settings['table_class_list'] = json_encode($classes);

   // remove default style
    $styles = array('width'=>'100%');
    $settings['table_default_styles'] = json_encode($styles);

    $settings['table_advtab'] = false;
        // echo'<pre>'; print_r($settings); echo '</pre>';

    return $settings;
}

add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', 'bootstrap_classes_tinymce');
```